# PostgreSQL timestamps - indexing

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, range

I am running a query where I look for a record, and another record a certain amount of time later.

Table definition:

```
(
  id integer primary key,
  gpsstatus character(2),
  datetime timestamp without time zone,
  lat numeric(9,6),
  lon numeric(9,6),
  alt numeric(9,4),
  time integer,
  datafileid integer,
  shape geometry,
  speed double precision,
  dist double precision,
  shape_utm geometry,
  lokalitet character(128),
  cowid integer
)
```

There are indexes on datetime,lokalitet,cowid,gpsstatus, gist-index on shape and shape_utm.

The points should be sampled every 5th seconds, so I tried to do

```
select <something more>,p1.timestamp 
from table p1, table p2 
where p1.timestamp + interval '5 secound' = p2.timestamp
```

That ran reasonably quick, but then I found out that I had lost quite a few points due to jitter in the sampling, so that the points may be from 4 to 6 seconds apart.

Then I tried:

```
where    (p2.timestamp, interval'0 second')
overlaps (p1.timestamp + interval '4 second', interval '2 second')
```

and that took for ages. I also tried the simpler solution:

```
WHERE p1.timestamp + interval '4 second' <= p2.timestamp
AND   p1.timestamp + interval '6 second' >= p2.timestamp
```

which also ended up being unusably slow.

The timestamp field has a normal index. Is there a special kind of index are something else that would make this query usable?

The query at the moment:

```
SELECT
    p1.cowid,
    p1.datetime,
    st_distance(p1.shape_utm, lead(p1.shape_utm)
      OVER (ORDER BY p1.datetime)) AS meters_obs,
    st_distance(p1.shape_utm, lead(p1.shape_utm, 720)
      OVER (ORDER BY p1.datetime)) AS meters_hour,
    observation.observation
  FROM (gpspoint p1 LEFT JOIN observation
                           ON (observation.gpspointid = p1.id)),
       status
  WHERE p1.gpsstatus = status.id
    AND status.use = true;
```

I may also get an an acceptable query time by asking for some specific intervals.

Comment: Are there only three possibilities, 4 or 5 or 6 seconds? Or could there be fractional seconds too?

Comment: There can be more records that you don't want to retrieve between the first and the second record? If there aren't you just need to retrieve the earlier one that has a timestamp higher than the first record.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Only three possibilities, the timestamps are truncated to seconds. - and yes, I've just found out that using chained ors or in() runs a lot faster, although the sql gets pretty ugly...

Comment: @Pablo: There may be records inbetween (although just as I described it, there are none) but I also need to look at what happens over longer intervals. But anyhow, how do I find the next record a unknown number of seconds later? having ?

Comment: @MortenSickel: "how do I find the next record a unknown number of seconds later?" Errr.... did you read Quassnoi's answer?

Comment: @MarkByers: It turned up just a moment after I wrote my question...

Comment: You should seriously reconsider use of the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` and `CHAR(n)` types. Both are there only for standards compliance, and both have very surprising semantics which tend to bite people who use them.  Consider `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (also known as `timestamptz`) if you want to record *a moment in time*. `VARCHAR(n)` is pretty much universally safer and faster in PostgresQL, without the surprising semantics around trailing blanks; many people just use `text`, which in PostgreSQL is the same thing without the length constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the previous record, you can do:

```
SELECT  p, LAG(p) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS pp
FROM    table p
ORDER BY
        timestamp
```

If you need a record `4` to `6` seconds before the current, use this:

```
SELECT  p1.*, p2.*
FROM    table p1
LEFT JOIN
        table p2
ON      p2.timestamp BETWEEN p1.timestamp - '4 seconds'::INTERVAL
                         AND p1.timestamp - '6 seconds'::INTERVAL
ORDER BY
        p1.timestamp
```

This may return multiple previous records if they all are in the range.

Comment: Thanks! Being quite new here, I'm still not able to +1 your answer. I'll come back to that later :-)

Comment: @MortenSickel: I'll lend a +1 hand.

Comment: Although, it turned out that the BETWEEN ... AND made the performance unusable again... (but, I learned a couple of really useful tricks there) The database has about 3 million rows, I am to extract between 7000 and 10000 of them. All relevant fields being indexed.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Thanks :-)

Comment: @MortenSickel: `BETWEEN` dooms the optimizer to use nested loops which are quite inefficient for this kind of query. Could you please post your exact query and the tables definitions?

Comment: Table definition:
id integer,gpsstatus character(2),datetime timestamp without time zone,lat numeric(9,6),lon numeric(9,6),alt numeric(9,4),time integer,datafileid integer,shape geometry,speed double precision,dist double precision,shape_utm geometry,lokalitet character(128),cowid integer. Id: Primary key There are indexes on datetime,lokalitet,cowid,gpsstatus, gist-index on shape and shape_utm.

Comment: @MortenSickel: please post it as update to your post, not in the comments.

Comment: @Quassnoi:`BETWEEN` does *not* force any particular type of plan in PostgreSQL. It is rewritten to `>=` and `<=` tests and the planner compares the costs of various plans, just like for everything else. Did you mean that you think that in this *particular* query probing for individual values would be less prone to use nested loops? Even that seems improbable; I'm wondering what you base it on.

Comment: @kgrittn: which else join algorithm can be used for `BETWEEN` (or any other ranged condition)?